# Creating a status update trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I have 2 tables like so:

**JOBS** table

```
Jobcode    UserId    Status
101        130       R
102        139       D
```

**USERS** table

```
UserId    Email
130       test@example.com
```

I want to create a trigger on insert and update that sends an email to my stored procedure:

```
EXEC dbo.SendMyEmail @email, @jobcode;
```

when the jobcode is inserted as 'D' or updated to 'D'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about data types etc but this should at least put you on the right track.
Hope it helps...

```
CREATE TRIGGER SendEmailOnStatusD

ON JOBS

-- trigger is fired when an update is made for the table
FOR UPDATE --You can add the same for INSERT

AS

    -- holds the UserID so we know which Customer was updated
    DECLARE @UserID int
    DECLARE @JobCode int

    SELECT @UserID = UserId, @JobCode = JobCode 
    FROM INSERTED WHERE [Status] = 'D' --If you want the old value before the update, use 'deleted' table instead of 'inserted' table

    IF (@UserID IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN

        -- holds the email
        DECLARE @email varchar(250)

        SELECT @email = Email FROM USERS WHERE UserId = @UserID

        EXEC SendMyEmail (@email, @jobcode);

    END

GO
```

**EDIT**:

Above code does not handle multiple updates, so for better practice see below option

```
CREATE TRIGGER SendEmailOnStatusD ON JOBS

-- trigger is fired when an update is made for the table
FOR UPDATE --You can add the same for INSERT

AS

    DECLARE @Updates table(UserID int, JobCode int, Email varchar(250))

    INSERT INTO @Updates (UserID, JobCode, Email)
    SELECT i.UserID, i.JobCode, u.Email
    FROM INSERTED i
        JOIN USERS u ON i.UserID = u.UserID
    WHERE [Status] = 'D'

    DECLARE @UserID int
    DECLARE @JobCode int
    DECLARE @Email varchar(250)

    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Updates)
    BEGIN

        SELECT TOP 1
            @UserID = UserID,
            @Email = Email, 
            @JobCode = JobCode
        FROM @Updates WHERE UserID = @UserID

        EXEC SendMyEmail (@email, @jobcode);

        DELETE FROM @Updates
        WHERE UserID = @UserID

    END

GO
```

Additionally, as discussed in the comments, sending emails from a trigger is also not the best, but as this is what the question asks for it has been included. I would recommend alternative options for sending emails such as a queue which has been mentioned in other answers.

Comment: I am forced to criticize an answer with a trigger that can't handle multiple rows inserted at once. Sorry about that. This is NOT best practice.

Comment: @ErikE Thanks for the feedback. I see you have already added a comprehensive solution. I also agree with you that the actual sending of an email should preferably not be done from the trigger.

Comment: Thanks! How about sharing the love?

Comment: @ErikE Btw, next time instead of 'criticizing' and down voting I would appreciate constructive suggestions and an opportunity to make improvements. Most of us are learning in some way or another =) Thanks

Comment: I downvote where warranted, then remove it if an edit occurs that fixes the defect. That way, if the poster never remediates it, the state of affairs is correct (flawed answers are properly downvoted). The poster has *every* opportunity to make improvements and tag me in a comment (which is why *I* comment, to provide a name to tag). If the problem is fixed then I remove my downvote. I'm not sure how I could make this any more constructive! Think about the greater context where thousands of people could copy and paste your code and never be protected from its flaws. *It's not about **you***.

Comment: @ErikE thank you for your clarification. I've edited the post somewhat but haven't had time for good testing, but as stated initially in the post, "this should at least put you on the right track". Keep up the good work with contributing to these forums ;)

Comment: It's nice to see your code handle multiple rows, though I have qualms about `UserID` being unique in updated rows of the Jobs table. Perhaps `JobCode` would be a better candidate. Also, a cursor would work (one of the rare situations where a cursor makes sense), so would inserting the `Inserted` table to a temp table with an identity column, or inserting to a temp table and doing a "destructive read" from it for each email by OUTPUT to another temp table. Or making the temp table have a "processed" bit column that gets set to 1 when done ala `UPDATE #I SET @UserID = UserID, processed = 1`

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, sending email in a trigger is not optimal.

Instead, you should just insert to a queue table, and have a process run frequently that checks the table and sends the email.

What happens if you get an error in your email procedure? It will force a rollback of your job completion status. Only you know whether that is minor or possibly catastrophic. But I can tell you for sure that DB best practice is to NOT do extended I/O during a DML operation.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Jobs_EnqueueEmail_IU ON dbo.Jobs FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT dbo.EmailQueue (UserID, JobCode)
SELECT UserID, JobCode
FROM
   Inserted I
   LEFT JOIN Deleted D
      ON I.JobCode = D.JobCode -- or proper PK columns
WHERE
   IsNull(D.Status, 'R') <> 'D'
   AND I.Status = 'D';
```

Tables needed:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EmailQueue (
   QueuedDate datetime NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT DF_EmailQueue_QeueueDate DEFAULT (GetDate()),
   UserID int NOT NULL,
   JobCode int NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT PK_EmailQueue PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (QueuedDate, UserID, JobCode)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.EmailSent (
   SentDate datetime NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT DF_EmailSent_SentDate DEFAULT (GetDate()),
   QueuedDate datetime NOT NULL,
   UserID int NOT NULL,
   JobCode int NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT PK_EmailSent PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (SentDate, QueuedDate, UserID, JobCode)
);
```

Then, run the following stored procedure once a minute from a SQL Job:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.EmailProcess
AS
DECLARE @Email TABLE (
   QueuedDate datetime,
   UserID int,
   JobCode int
);
DECLARE
   @EmailAddress nvarchar(255),
   @JobCode int;

WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN

   DELETE TOP 1 Q.*
   OUTPUT Inserted.QueuedDate, Inserted.UserID, Inserted.JobCode
   INTO @Email (QueuedDate, UserID, JobCode)
   FROM dbo.EmailQueue Q WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, READPAST)
   ORDER BY QueuedDate;

   IF @@RowCount = 0 RETURN;

   SELECT @EmailAddress = U.EmailAddress, @JobCode = E.JobCode
   FROM
      @Email E
      INNER JOIN dbo.User U
         ON E.UserID = U.UserID;

   EXEC dbo.SendMyEmail @EmailAddress, @JobCode;

   DELETE E
   OUTPUT QueuedDate, UserID, JobCode
   INTO dbo.EmailSent (QueuedDate, UserID, JobCode)
   FROM @Email E;

END;
```

The delete pattern and locks I used are very specifically chosen. If you change them or change the delete pattern *in any way* it is almost certain you will break it. Handling locks and concurrency is *hard*. Don't change it.

Note: I typed all the above without checking anything on a SQL Server. It is likely there are typos. Please forgive any.